# HTML form - redirect respond

Tags: html, forms, http

Let's say I have a form which when I submit calls an API. That API returns some data and this data is finally shown on the form. What if in that API I want to create a file and return it back for the download. I tried that and while it is in general working, the form continues waiting for the respond. Is there a way to trick the form to complete the submit action?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try something like that:

```js
const data = { username: 'john', email: 'test@test.com' };

fetch('https://example.com/api/test', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
.then((response) => {
  // CREATE FILE HERE
  response.json();
})
.then(data => {
  // DOWNLOAD THE CREATED FILE HERE...
  console.log('Success:', data);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).